# Reverse chronological view for "flagged post list"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

Currently when a moderator views the profile of a user, and selects to look at the history of flagged posts of that user, the list is presented *chronologically*.

I think it would be better if the list is presented *reverse chronologically*. Most of the time when I check the history of flagged posts for a user is to see whether the user's behaviour has improved since the last warning given, or if there has been a recent trend in problematic behaviour. And I think in general it is more useful (for moderator decisions) to see the recent behaviour of a user than "ancient history" (forgive and forget, right?)

Granted, all it changes is whether I have to scroll to bottom on a page. But this change would make life somewhat easier for the moderators, I think. So, just to high-light the request:

> Please change the "flagged posts" view of individual users to show the posts in reverse chronological order.

Comment: Meh, Stack Exchange sites wore out my poor scroll wheel a long time ago, but I can't see what this change would hurt. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the original sort order was unintentional. That has since been fixed - the flags list is now shown in reverse chronological order, with the most recent flags at the top.